# Shortest and longest string in array

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I have an assignment, I need to create a method that receives `(char * * ch,site_t size)`.

`ch` is an array of addresses to `char` arrays, I need to make it so that the shortest element will be first (address and place) and longest will be last one (address and place). Here is what  made so far although it doesn't work on array size 5 (tried only on size 4):

(Note: I used `char * arr[]` but I planned to changing it once I get the program working with this type of variable.)

```
void AdressSwitcher(char * arr[],size_t size){ 
char*shortest=arr[0];
char*shortestFollower=NULL;
char*longest=arr[1];
char*longestFollower=NULL;
 for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
      if(strlen(arr[i])<(strlen(shortest))){
        shortest=arr[i];
        arr[i]=arr[0];
      }
      arr[0]=shortest;
}
  for(size_t i=1;i<size;i++){
      if(strlen(arr[i])>(strlen(longest))){
        longest=arr[i];
         arr[i]=arr[size-1];
     }
        arr[size-1]=longest;

// }
 for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
   printf("%s %p", arr[i],arr[i]);
   printf("\n");
 }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the problem is about the size of the array (4 vs. 5), more about its contents. Please provide example data that you see misbehaving (see also [mre]).

Comment: I would suggest you start over and try to debug one thing at a time. First get the shortest working, then you can do the rest. And I would split that part into finding the right element and then doing one swap to bring it into the right place.

Comment: That's assuming you only have to do the shortest and longest, not sort the whole array, which would be a different problem.

Comment: @NickZzie If for example the array has two equal longest strings then which string is placed to the last element of the array?

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SO. This problem can be easily solved with the following method:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *escape_double_quotes(const char *s)
{
        char *result = calloc((strlen(s) * 2) + 1, sizeof(char));
        size_t resultIndex = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
                if (s[i] == '"')
                {
                        result[resultIndex] = '\\';
                        resultIndex++;
                        result[resultIndex] = '"';
                        resultIndex++;
                        continue;
                }
                result[resultIndex] = s[i];
                resultIndex++;
        }
        return result;
}

void longestAndShortest(char **arr, const size_t size)
{
        if (size <= 1)
                return;

        size_t shortIndex = 0;
        size_t shortSize = strlen(arr[0]);

        size_t longIndex;
        size_t longSize = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
                size_t b = strlen(arr[i]);

                if (b > longSize)
                {
                        longIndex = i;
                        longSize = b;
                }
                if (b < shortSize)
                {
                        shortIndex = i;
                        shortSize = b;
                }
        }
        printf("The shortest size of the array was %lu, the index of that being %lu and the contents of that being \"%s\".\n", shortSize, shortIndex, escape_double_quotes(arr[shortIndex]));
        printf("The longest size of the array was %lu, the index of that being %lu and the contents of that being \"%s\".\n", longSize, longIndex, escape_double_quotes(arr[longIndex]));

        return;
}

int main(void)
{
        char **array = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 8);

        array[0] = malloc(128);
        strcpy(array[0], "World!");

        array[1] = malloc(128);
        strcpy(array[1], "Hello");

        longestAndShortest(array, 2);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                free(array[i]);
        free(array);

        return 0;
}
```

From here you should be able to complete the rest.

Please work on writing more tidy code. Your future self will thank you.
Have a great day!